# Member function of a templated class can't return a pointer to member structure?

Tags: c++, templates

This code doesn't compile (gives errors C2059, C2065, C2072, C2143, C2146, C2447, C2470, C4430)
But does if you change B* to an inbuild type like int.
Any ideas?

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
private:
    struct B
    {
        T key;
    };

    B* foobar(T key);

};

template <typename T>
B* A<T>::foobar(T key) 
{
    B* ptr = new B;
    B->key = key;
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few errors in your method.

1) the return type's scope must be properly qualified.

2) You have to set the `key` if a `A::<T>::B` instance, not a `B`.

Try this:

```
template <typename T>
typename A<T>::B* A<T>::foobar(T key) // fix error 1)
{
    B* ptr = new B();
    ptr->key = key;  // fix error 2)
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: What is the significance of new B() ? Are we calling the default initialiser? Is there any difference wrt to just 'new B'?

Comment: @IshanBhatnagar in this case there is no difference. You can use `new B`, which also calls the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The return type should be `typename A<T>::B*`, not just `B*`:

```
template<typename T>
typename A<T>::B* A<T>::foobar(T key)
{
   //..
}
```

Note also `typename` keyword in the return type.